# Getting specific part of HTML document using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to find a way to get a specific part of text out of an HTML document that doesn't really have any tags using python. The HTML code looks like this.

```
<h1 class="col">
    <small> Text1 </small>
    Text2
</h1>
```

I'm trying to get the part that says `text 2` without getting the part that says `text1`. I'm currently using Beatiful Soup in my python code so it would be handy if there was a solution using this library.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to get your goal e.g. via `contents`:

```
soup.h1.contents[-1].strip()
```

or `next_sibling`:

```
soup.h1.small.next_sibling.strip()
```

or `find_all(text=True, recursive=False)`:

```
''.join(soup.h1.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
```

and many more ...

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<h1 class="col">
    <small> Text1 </small>
    Text2
</h1>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
print(soup.h1.contents[-1].strip())
print(soup.h1.small.next_sibling.strip())
print(''.join(soup.h1.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip())
```

##### Output

```
Text2
Text2
Text2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using split and soup.find

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<h1 class="col">
<small> Text1 </small>
Text2
</h1>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
txt = soup.find('h1').text.split()[1]  # -> 'Text2'
```